# CSV file function should return none if empty, error if file not found

Tags: python, csv, file

My code is supposed to read a csv file and return information as a list of dictionaries. However, it does not work.

```
import csv
def read_csv(fname):
    stu_list = []
    try:
        with open(fname, 'r') as students:
            reader = (csv.reader(students))
            for row in reader:
                avg = sum(float(grade) for grade in row[2:]) / 10
                rounded_avg = round(avg, 3)
                student_info = {'name': row[0], 'section':row[1], 'scores':[grade for grade in row[2:]], 'average':rounded_avg}
                stu_list.append(student_info)
            if len(stu_list) == 0:
                return None
            print(stu_list)
    except:
        print(f"Error occurred when opening {fname} to read")
        return None
```

Comment: Where does your code `return` anything other than None?

Comment: "However, it does not work." Please clarify. What exactly happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: Presumably you meant to return stu_list...

Answer (score 2):

Basically all you need to do is return `stu_list`. So replace

```
print(stu_list)
```

with

```
return stu_list
```

and put the print at the call site. Something like

```
print(read_csv('students.csv'))
```

Personally i think the `return None` stuff is kinda unpythonic, as it interrupts the flow of the happy path (where there are no errors). I would allow the exceptions to propagate to the user and let them decide how to handle them.

Some updated code

```
import csv

def read_csv(fname):
    stu_list = []
    with open(fname, 'r') as students:
        for row in csv.reader(students):
            name, section, *scores = row
            avg = sum(float(grade) for grade in scores) / len(scores)
            student_info = {'name': name, 'section': section, 'scores': scores, 'average': round(avg, 3)}
            stu_list.append(student_info)
        return stu_list


if __name__ =='__main__':
    from sys import argv, exit

    if len(argv) < 2:
        print('must provide file name')
        exit(1)

    filename = argv[1]
    try:
        values = read_csv(filename)
        if values:
            print(values)
        else:
            print(f"Error student list {filename} is empty")
    except:
        print(f"Error occurred when opening {filename} to read")
```

Comment: Thank you! I am a beginner coder and this helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of observations:

1. When the list of students is not empty, I don't see any statement to return it. That is why you get `None`. To fix it, at the place where you `print(stu_list)`, return the `stu_list`.
2. Do not use bare `except`, meaning `except` without any specific error. This practice is dangerous as it will hide serious errors, making debugging extremely hard. I suggest to use the `FileNotFoundError` in this case. Better yet, I would not use try/except at all and let the caller handle the error.
3. When calculating the average, I use `statistics.mean` instead of hard-coding `10` as number of grades.

Code:

```py
import csv
import statistics


def read_csv(fname):
    stu_list = []
    try:
        with open(fname, "r") as students:
            reader = csv.reader(students)
            for row in reader:
                scores = [float(grade) for grade in row[2:]]
                avg = statistics.mean(scores)
                rounded_avg = round(avg, 3)
                student_info = {
                    "name": row[0],
                    "section": row[1],
                    "scores": scores,
                    "average": rounded_avg,
                }
                stu_list.append(student_info)
            if len(stu_list) == 0:
                return None
            return stu_list
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Error occurred when opening {fname} to read")
        return None
```

Comment: I agree with suggestion no. 2. There's no real reason here to use a try/except clause. The automatically generated error message from a FileNotFoundError is just as informative as the print message.